# ERROR: Missing data for not-null field - Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

In redshift I am using the code below, but when I tried to insert the data into a table or temp table, I get the message ERROR: Missing data for not-null field. Any thoughts on this issue?

select
COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(metadata, 'cardInfo', 'value', 'amount')::float, 0.0) AS giftcard_amount
into #temp
from aw.payouts

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue there are null and blank values (cardInfo), I adjusted my case statement and it works as expected.

```
(CASE 
        WHEN metadata like '%"cardInfo"%' 
       AND JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(metadata, 'cardInfo', 'value', 'amount') IS NOT NULL 
        THEN 
        CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(metadata, 'cardInfo', 'value', 'amount') AS FLOAT) 
        ELSE 0.0 
        END) AS giftcard_amount
```